# JFrame appearance and style

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, jframe, look-and-feel

I would like to know if there is anyway to create JFrame that look like Windows 7 Aero task-bar. I mean I want the whole frame look like that by being transparent and blurring the scene in the background.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) will help a little.

Comment: This just makes the window transparent, I also need to blur the background image

Comment: Have a look at `UIManager` class, especially the `setLookAndFeel()` method.

Comment: *"I want the **whole** frame look like that"* Why?  I have Aero effect enabled for borders and title bar of frames and like it, but would not want **any** app. to have that effect across the **entire** app.  What is so special about your app. that makes that effect the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

As **Swing** is a **PLAF** (Pluggable Look And Feel), there are few options to get look and feel of windows with UIManager class....

Pls try this link... it will give you some idea

http://www.scribd.com/doc/44575030/13-Basic-Swing